# Console app running in Google Cloud

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add my project to Google cloud under "App Engine". I have added it through the "Cloud Shell" using Git run the "dotnet restore" command which all works correctly.

However my application is a console app and not a web application. I can't find any documentation related to a console app running on Google cloud. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a simple console? Based on your tag, it's asp.net core and asp.net core is a console app. 
If that's the case, you can deploy it to Google AppEngine Flex - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart

You can also deploy it using a Custom runtime and just put your custom configs - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) is a web and mobile applications platform, even tho you could make it work for your app if you configure it to respond to the IP address provided, there is no guide for it since is not a predetermined function. I believe that [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) would be a better fit for your application, although you have to do all the configurations by yourself. Maybe you can find a pre-made solution on [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/).